# How to set up TwoFactor and Lockout settings with ASP.NET Boilerplate templates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, settings, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-identity

I've been using ASP.NET Boilerplate as a template for my application as a starting point.  I was in the process of modifying the login process to implement 2FA.  However, I'm not sure where to put those configuration settings.  In a previous application using .NET MVC with .NET Identity, I was able to do this in a class we had as `ApplicationUserManager` that inherited `UserManager`.  This is how I had things configured:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<User> store) : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<User>(context.Get<Db>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365*500);

        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<User>()
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
        });

        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }

        return manager;
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET Boilerplate, there are a lot of powerful tools and many interfaces that can be implemented to assist in the login process.  I've seen a GitHub post where [disable lockout feature](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3737) was discussed, and it looks like I should be able to add to my `SettingsManager` database options for `MaxFailedAccessAttempts` and `DefaultLockoutTimeSpan`, but I'm not sure that just by adding them to the database that they will be picked up auto-magically, especially if I do not name them correctly.  There is already a class of constant values for `EmailSettings` that I was able to use here:

```
public void Create()
{
    // Emailing
    AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.DefaultFromAddress, "developer@developer.com");
    AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.DefaultFromDisplayName, "do not reply");
    AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Host, "smtp.gmail.com");
    AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Port, "587");
    AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.UserName, "developer@developer.com");
    AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Password, "SomePassword");
    AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.EnableSsl, "true");
    AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials, "false");

    // Languages
    AddSettingIfNotExists(LocalizationSettingNames.DefaultLanguage, "en");
}
```

There is also a class in the `Core` project — `AppSettingNames`, which contains a value for `UiTheme`.  I suppose I can add the constant values there.  However, if I do this, do I need to name these settings identically to what the `UserManager` attributes are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant constants are in [`AbpZeroSettingNames`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/bc266e3503fcb2825684ec829cc356815f94f397/src/Abp.Zero.Common/Zero/Configuration/AbpZeroSettingNames.cs).

```cs
// DefaultLockoutTimeSpan
AddSettingIfNotExists(
    AbpZeroSettingNames.UserManagement.UserLockOut.DefaultAccountLockoutSeconds,
    int.MaxValue.ToString() // 2,147,483,647 seconds, just over 68 years
);

// MaxFailedAccessAttempts
AddSettingIfNotExists(
    AbpZeroSettingNames.UserManagement.UserLockOut.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout,
    "5"
);
```

Unfortunately, `int.MaxValue` in seconds only allows the application to lock out the user for just over 68 years at a time, shy of the 500 years that you used to configure.